# Pyinstaller,how to solve "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cogs'" error while trying to convert py file to.exe?

Tags: python, discord.py, pyinstaller

I've been trying to convert my **main.py** file to .exe so users don't have to install python

```
pyinstaller --onefile -w main.py
```

.After I create the .exe file,I try to run the exe and i get the above error.I've been using **cogs** for categorizing my commands.**In the below photo,these modules are must be used in .exe version**.How can i do that?Could someone help me?

The full error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "main.py", line 212, in <module>

    client.load_extension(f"cogs.{filename[:-3]}")

  File "discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 674, in load_extension

  File "importlib\util.py", line 94, in find_spec

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cogs'
```

The photo of main.py and other files:
[main.py and other files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnIcl.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#Convert .py to .exe don't use python ver 3.9 will not work, recommend 3.8:

pip install pyinstaller

#to convert to a simple exe file the exe file will be in your dist folder
pyinstaller 'fileName.py'

#to convert to a onefile exe file the exe file will be in your dist folder
pyinstaller --onefile 'fileName.py'

#to convert to a onefile exe file and the python window will not appear
pyinstaller -w --onefile 'fileName.py'
```

Comment: Thank you it helped :)

Comment: Im glad ! @Harasiva4234